# Event backpressed WP 8.1

Tags: c#, events, exception, runtime-error

I used the following code for manipulating the event backpressed, but it isn't working

```
 private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (frame == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            frame.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

It returns this error:

> Error  1   The type or namespace name 'BackPressedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can anyone help me, or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to handle a specific key pressed, you usually receive those all as a single `KeyPressed` event or such.

Also, when dealing with events, you actually add your handler to the event, which has a specific `delegate` that should point you in the right direction.